# Calling Rust from C# with IntPtr fails on Enum (EntryPointNotFound)

Tags: c#, rust, ffi

I'm trying to use the 'opaque pointer' style of FFI where the C# (Unity) code only sees my Rust type as an IntPtr that it has to pass around to various Rust functions. However I am getting EntryPointNotFound exceptions as soon as the function that I'm referencing refers to an enum.

The two functions which *don't* refer to an enum work fine, but the function that does fails to bind apparently and throws a EntryPointNotFoundException. I've included the symbols in the dynlib (bundle) file to show that the symbol is in the file.

I've tried without the "C" in `extern "C"` in Rust, and `CallingConvention=CDecl` and `CallingConvention=StdCall` in C# but that didn't change the situation - the int and int pointer function will run (their respective print functions indeed print), but the enum pointer function just throws EntryPointNotFoundException and "enum pointer fine" is never printed.

### ptr_test.rs

```
pub enum TestEnum{Test(i32)}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn ptr_test(arg: *mut i32) {}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn int_test(arg: i32) {}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn consume_ptr(arg: *mut TestEnum) {}
```

### RustTest.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class RustTest : MonoBehaviour {
    [DllImport("libptr_test")]
    private static extern void ptr_test(IntPtr x);

    [DllImport("libptr_test")]
    private static extern void int_test(int x);

    [DllImport("libptr_test")]
    private static extern void consume_ptr (IntPtr x);

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        print ("Hello World!");
        ptr_test (new IntPtr (0));
        print ("pointer fine");
        int_test (0);
        print ("int fine");
        consume_ptr (new IntPtr (0));
        print ("enum pointer fine");
        print ("Done!");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

### nm -gU carved-unity/carved/Assets/libptr_test.bundle

```
...
00000000000009c0 T _consume_ptr
0000000000000990 T _int_test
0000000000000960 T _ptr_test
...
```

Comment: say @user1058064 - I'm just curious, what were you using Rust for in this?  cheers..

Comment: Real answer: because combining Rust, Unity, and (soon to be) F# seemed like an interesting project. Good answer: I'm making a minecraft like using a sparse voxel octree (I. E. 8 identical voxels get combined into 1 bigger one) and would like to calculate voxel visibility by ray-casting. Each frame throw out a thousand rays and the voxels that get hit get rendered. Ray casting is expensive enough and doesn't involve allocating any memory so that's my (thin) justification for doing it in Rust.

Comment: If you're interested, [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/089b201c1482e541e135) is mostly the code that I've got so far.

Comment: sounds like a fascinating exploration! just BTW you probably know that unity has excellent occlusion culling (one of the things they got right!)  sometimes we write our own but typically it's the stuff

Comment: It's not just occlusion culling but also frustum culling (okay this is pretty much free with unity too), and draw-distance/LoD too in that big objects far away will get rendered but you only see the smaller objects when you're up close. Another benefit (and this was honestly the main driver for using this) is that I want to implement a "cut-away" feature so the 3rd-person camera can see through roofs and so on. Doing this without changing the model is easy with ray-casting - simply ignore collisions happening over a certain height.

Comment: yes, when I say "occlusion culling" that certainly includes occlusion by the frustrum  :)  Yes, that is superbly built-in to Unity (I'm a big Unity-criticizer! But it's something they do a great job on.)  Note too that LOD is absolutely built in to Unity, and again (surprisingly! heh) something they do a perfect job on. (One point - it's worth noting that, much as with PhysX - it's absolutely impossible for us to out-write the Unity guys or the PhysX guys: there is man-decades in their code but, overwhelmingly, they do it on the metal, on GPU, so we can't even get close to their performance.)

Comment: Just so you know, regarding cut-aways, FYI that is very common in Unity projects.  It's just one line of code in a shader, or (if that's too much code! :) ) just as you say using a raycast it is half a line of code.  Actually it's not even half a line of code, it's ".enable =" so it's only nine characters of code! heh!

Comment: Wow, I had the exact same idea (sparse voxel octree for a minecraft lookalike) and was curious about the use of Rust as well. What are the odds!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not able to reproduce your behavior. Here is my Rust source:

```
pub enum TestEnum{Test(i32)}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn consume_ptr(arg: *mut TestEnum) {
    println!("{:?}", arg);
}
```

I compile it with `rustc --crate-type=dylib example.rs`

I then copied the resulting example.dll into a .NET Console application, and using this P/Invoke signature:

```cs
[DllImport("example.dll", EntryPoint = "consume_ptr", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern void consume_ptr(int arg);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    consume_ptr(0);
}
```

And `0x0` is printed to the console. I don't know how to properly create and Marshal a Rust enumeration from .NET, but it doesn't produce an "EntryPointNotFoundException", and have confirmed that it is properly exported by looking at the exports with [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com).

Comment: Well I tried again this morning and it suddenly works now. Thanks for your help. I'm guessing that the problem lay somewhere in my (still very manual) build process and so clearing everything caused it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I kept running into this `EntryPointNotFoundException` as well. I had a Rust project called `myproject`, exported `myproject.dll` and created a C# bindings project called `MyProject` which imported the DLL. Yet my symbols were never found in it.

The reason was simply a name clash of the assembly generated from the C# code (`MyProject.dll`) and the Rust library `myproject.dll` in the output directory. Just renaming one of the projects solved it for me. Took me a while to figure out, hope this helps someone avoid the same mistake.